# Struts 2 manually call a custom validation in an action

Tags: validation, struts2

We have used Struts 2 validation with lots of custom validation to validate our forms.

```java
@Validations( 
    customValidators =      
           { @CustomValidator(type = "AccountFormat", fieldName = "accountNo") }
)
```

Also we can can manually validate a form by overriding the validate method

```java
public void validate() {
    //Username can't be blank
    if(username.equals("")) {
        addFieldError("username", "The Username can't be empty");
    }
```

Is it possible to call the `custom validations` in the `validate()`.

**Why we need it ?!**
All validation rules are packed in custom validations, which is perfect. There are some few forms which need to have their own manual validation. We end up cut and pasting some of custom validation rules in these manual validation forms too, it would be best if we could call validations here

Comment: You may try and if it doesn't work came back here with the valid question, as far as it's written this question is off-topic.

Comment: Of course I had tried, but could not find any solution at all.

Comment: With what exactly are you having trouble? Create an instance of your custom validator, set properties and call `validate` method of it.

Comment: @RomanC @AleksandrM I hoped I could do it easier with Struts API, and path only parameters which I used to configure via annotation, some thing like: `FieldValidatorSupport validator= SomeFactory.getValidator("AccountFormat");` and then `validator.setFieldName("accountNo");`  and finally `validator.validate();` Is it possible ?!

Comment: Instead of `SomeFactory.getValidator` call `new YourCustomValidator()`, set field name and call `validate`. Easy enough? :)

Comment: @AleksandrM well then :) If you send it  as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can create an instance of your custom validator, set required properties (field name, value stack, ...) and call `validate` method...

BUT it is not the best way to handle such cases. What you are going to do if you need to validate values outside of the action context (e.g. in some web service)?

The better solution would be to pull validation logic from custom validator to some separate class, which you can call from anywhere in your code, and write your Struts2 custom validator as a wrapper that calls that class.